# I had used Quartz in my Java web-application but when Quartz will execute after its execution, Tomcat is being off.

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I wrote a code in Quartz that will update database on a daily basis exactly once a day.
I am using Eclipse in my web-application so had started the Tomcat through Eclipse.

But after updating the database from Quartz it is forcing the Tomcat to be terminated in Eclipse. So my application is not working after the Quartz portion is running (due to Tomcat termination). The messages I got in Eclipse 4 Quartz is displayed below:

```
Job name:Event Update1
Group name:mysql
Trigger name:cronTrigger4Event1
Firing Time:Mon Jan 24 14:30:00 IST 2011
dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())   : 2011-01-24
Inserting values in Mysql database table!
1 row affected
Jan 24, 2011 2:30:00 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

[INFO] 24 Jan 2011 14:30:05.506 Thread-34 [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler]
Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.

[INFO] 24 Jan 2011 14:30:05.506 Thread-34 [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler]
Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.

[INFO] 24 Jan 2011 14:30:05.506 Thread-34 [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler]
Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling `shutdown()` on the Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem in tomcat and eclipse not in quartz itself so you have two solutions

1- get the tomcat out of eclipse and deploy you application manually, don't forget to give you application server more memory.

2- get you schedule jobs out of you application and use the Linux system cron jobs.